# AUTH 0 reset password not sending email

Tags: auth0

I am using AUTH 0 server.

I created a user and mail verified.

next I tried to call reset password api but not getting any mail .

how can I solve this .

```
url - https://{{auth0_domain}}/dbconnections/change_password

{
  "client_id": "errt",
  "email": "mahi123@mailinator.com",
  "connection": "test"
}
```

but not getting email.. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

see https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#change-password

```
POST https://YOUR_DOMAIN/dbconnections/change_password
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  "email": "EMAIL",
  "connection": "CONNECTION",
}
```

Things to check:

- HTTP method is `POST`
- `Content-Type` HTTP header is `application/json`
- `client_id` needs to be a valid client ID from an Auth0 application
- `connection` needs to be same connection as the user specified e.g. "Username-Password-Authentication" - you can find this out by searching for the user in the Auth0 web portal:
  [image: List item]

If you still have issues, please post the HTTP response you're getting...

Comment: All settings are correct. and getting the response as email is sent. but email is not getting

Comment: are you integrating with SendGrid to send email? Perhaps you can log into SendGrid to see what's happening there with email delivery...